# How can I turn my rear window into a one-way mirror?

Tags: window, mirrors

I still want to be abl to see out the back of my car, but at the same time I want to give all those obnoxious pricks who drive around with their high-beams on at night even when they're behind another car a well-deserved attitude adjustment.  How can I turn my rear window into a one-way mirror, like cops use on TV for interrogation rooms?

Comment: The rear window on almost all vehicles is slanted.  There is almost no chance that light will be reflected specularly back into the eyes of the driver behind you.  Even if it did, it would also annoy people who were driving with their low beams on.  As such, I'd expect this to be illegal in almost all areas.

Answer (score 4):

In many ways, a better solution would be to install an [auto-dimming mirror](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_pObzXUzE8&feature=youtu.be):

- most auto manufacturers nowadays offer this feature as an option
- the dimming gel relies on light-sensor input to decide whether to lighten or darken
- installing window tint reduces night-driving visibility
- not all legislations approve of the installation of window tint.

[image: mirror]
<sub>(source: [gentex.com](https://www.gentex.com/images/auto/why_dimming_picture.gif))</sub>

Auto-dimming mirrors do require an electrical power supply, but should be quite easy to retrofit into a vehicle which has interior cabin/reading lights, since the wiring for the lights can be spliced into.

Comment: This is a better solution. But i am wondering why the OP is either not aware of or does not have manual version of this fitted on his car.I thought it is standard equipment.

Comment: @Anarach Lot of people don't know about the manual dimming feature. All most all the cars have it.

Answer (score 3):

This easiest way to do this is by using limo tint or [one way mirror window tint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004S7HPJ0).

[image]

The thing to be careful of here is to be ware of local laws which may be at issue with your designs. At least in the US, most states require that you do not put this type of tint forward of the B-pillar (post at the rear of the front door) so as to not impede the driver's vision.

Comment: I'll comment that overtinting the rear window — a fairly common modification — makes it harder or impossible for following drivers to see _through_ your car, so they can react more quickly to brake lights on cars in front of you. I'm a motorcycle rider, and maintaining a space cushion at all times is critical. Please don't go overboard here.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I agree with you (hence the upvote), but don't forget, you can't look through vans, busses and lorries either.

Comment: @KrijnToet Certainly true. Following those vehicles closely is also hazardous for motorcyclists.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - Everything is hazardous for motorcyclists ... it's a tough life for y'all.